# Extract tar archive excluding a specific folder and its contents

Tags: linux, tar

With PHP I am using `exec("tar -xf archive.tar -C /home/user/target/folder")` to extract the contents of a specific archive (archive.tar) into the target directory (/home/user/target/folder), so that all existing contents of the target directory will be overwritten by the new ones that are contained in the archive.

It works fine and all files in the target directory are being overwritten after extract, but there is one directory in the archive that I would like to omit (from extracting and thus overwriting the existing one in the target folder)...

For example, the archive.tar contains:

folderA/

folderB/

folderC/

folderD/

fileA.php

fileB.php

fileC.xml

How could I extract (and overwrite) all *except* (for example) `folderC/`? In other words, I want folderC and its contents to remain intact in the user's directory and not be overwritten by the one contained in the tar archive.

Any suggestions?

(Tar on the hosting server is GNU version 1.23.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use '--exclude' to omit a folder:

```
tar -xf archive.tar -C /home/user/target/folder" --exclude="folderC"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the `--exclude PATTERN` option in the `tar` tool.

Check: [tar on linuxcommand.org](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/tar1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Write `--exclude='./folder'` at the beginning of the tar command.

In your case that is,

```
exec("tar -x --exclude='./C' -f archive.tar -C /home/user/target/folder")
```

Comment: Incorrect. 

Use `--exclude` /after/ the source and destination have been specified.

Comment: That depends on the version.

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side, you could remove all write permissions from the folder. For example:

```
$ chmod 000 folderC/
```

An then do a normal tar extract (as regular user). You'll get some error messages on console, but your folder will remain untouched.... At the end of the tar, change back your folder original permissions. For example:

```
$ chmod 775 folderC/
```

Of course '--exclude' tar option is the right solution to this particular problem, but, if you are not completely 100% sure about a command syntax, and yor're handling **critical** data, my solution puts you on the safe side :-).

Comment: This is a very unnecessary (and bad practice) way to do this. The built in method `--exclude` exists for this very requirement.

Comment: When handling **critical** production data, as a responsible sysadm, I do always double protect my actions, when possible... So OP could do both (`chmod` and `--exclude`), for example, expecially if he had to post a question on SO to get the work done, meaning he is not quite experienced with the command...

Comment: I'm concerned that your suggestion  detracts from what OP is asking, and may confuse further - especially if (as you mention) OP is not overly familiar with the command.